# Когда правильно употреблять «насторо́женно», а когда «насторожённо»? Характерные примеры использования

Tags: орфография, словообразование, морфология, причастия, наречия

Когда правильно употреблять «насторо́женно», а когда «насторожённо»?
Можно характерные **примеры употребления**, чтобы их как понятный образец использовать, а то я что-то не пойму?..

Посмотрел в онлайн-словаре – различается минимум три случая:

1. Просто **насторо́женно** (НАРЕЧИЕ).
2. **Насторожённо** от *насторожи́ть* (ПРИЧАСТИЕ прошедшего времени, в страдательном залоге).
3. **Насторожённо** от *насторожённый* (ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ).

Я запутался – когда какое употребляется?

Все три варианта – разные части речи (наречие, причастие, прилагательное).
Мне нужны примеры их употребления, чтобы понять, в чём различия и когда какая форма употребляется.

(Это нужно для того, чтобы преобразовывать сокращённо-унифицированную форму *настороженно* в полноценную форму с ударением или ё.)

Comment: Вы хоть один-то пример сами приведите. Из числа тех, которые вызывают сомнения.

Comment: _znanija2021: **Насторожённо** от насторожи́ть (ПРИЧАСТИЕ прошедшего времени, в страдательном залоге)._ === **НЕТ, не так.** Причастие от _насторожить_ пишется так: _**насторожено**_ (с "е" и одним "н"). В каком словаре Вы нашли приведённое Вами написание?

Comment: slava1947, в словаре [udarenieru.ru](https://udarenieru.ru/) : [настороженно](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=настороженно) [насторожить](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=насторожить) [настороженный](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=настороженный) - это те варианты, которые я нашёл (этот словарь сам все варианты не всегда показывает)

Answer (score 2):

```
      Когда правильно употреблять «насторо́женно», а когда «насторожённо»?
```

Варианты равноправные. Малый академический словарь:

> насторо́женно И насторожённо. нареч. к настороженный. По
> городу Катя шла настороженно, прятала лицо в воротник полушубка,
> цепким взглядом осматривала прохожих. Марков, Сибирь

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/mas/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%

У Лопатина в Орфографическом словаре:

> насторожённый1; кр. ф. -ён, -ена, прич.
> насторожённый2 и настороженный; кр. ф. -ён, -ена и -ожен, -ожена
> (находящийся в напряженном ожидании, насторожившийся: бойцы
> насторожены), -ён, -ённа и -ожен, -оженна (выражающий напряженное
> ожидание: лица, взгляды насторожённы и настороженны), прил.

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/orthography_lopatin/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82

> насторожённо и настороженно, нареч. Русский
> орфографический словарь Лопатина

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/orthography_lopatin/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82

Как видим, и причастие, и прилагательное, и наречие имеют два варианта ударения, мне видится произношение с ударением на О более книжным, на Ё более разговорным.

Краткая форма причастия среднего рода довольно редкая, но она возможна: *Общество было (каково? что сделано?) настороженО (и насторОжено) происходящими событиями в Африке.*

Наречие: *Ночью меня разбудил чей-то взгляд, моя собака сидела около кровати и (как?) насторОженно (насторожённо)смотрела на меня.*

Краткое прилагательное: *Выражение собачьей морды было (каково?) насторОженно (насторожённо)  и недовольно.*

Краткое страдательное причастие: *Ухо собаки (каково? что сделано?) насторОжено (настороженО), а голова повернута.*